# Масштабировать отображение карты Yandex, при отображении в WKWebView

Tags: swift, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Все очень мелко отображается, как сделать так, что бы стандартные элементы навигации, были крупными в телефонах с высоким разрешением.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать тэг meta name="viewport" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: Спасибо, действительно помогло. Сделал как тут: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40830148/5437012